# bash command: search for class in file system of jars

Tags: bash, search, class, jar, archive

I'm wanting to recursively search my maven repository (an n folder deep heirachy of jars) for a specific class inside an unknown jar.

jar -tvf myJar.jar | grep ClassIWant.class works great for a known jar but I'm having problems piping/chaining bash commands to achieve a recursive search.

Any hints much appreciated.

Related: [BASH :: find file in archive from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682130/bash-find-file-in-archive-from-command-line)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, I could probably get something going as a script, but was ideally hoping for a one liner.

Comment: Found the same question answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500141/find-a-jar-file-given-the-class-name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Post already exists. Solved here [Find a jar file given the class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500141/find-a-jar-file-given-the-class-name) Thanks for the alternatives.

Answer (score 9):

```
find -name \*.jar | xargs -n1 -iFILE sh -c "jar tvf FILE | sed -e s#^#FILE:#g" | grep classIWant\\.class | cut -f1 -d:
```

Answer (score 3):

Bash 4+

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*.jar
do
  jar -tvf "$file" | grep ....
done
```

<4++

```
find /path -type f -name "*.jar" | while read -r FILE
do
     jar -tvf "$FILE" | grep ....
done
```